1-hour connection at LHR: reasonable?
I booked my Christmas trip through United as a single ticket, but only now realized that my connection time in LHR is only 1 hour.
It looks like my flight from Vienna arrives at terminal 2 and the departing flight also goes from T2. Nonetheless one still has to go through security and document check (since it's a USA-bound flight).
So my questions:

Is it reasonable to expect to make my flight to IAH with just 1 hour connection time? United sells it so I guess they see it as feasible.
Would I be eligible for monetary compensation if my VIE-LHR flight is delayed and I arrive to Houston late? There are plenty of flights to Houston so I can be re-booked no problem. 


Try also to find if there are further connections from LHR to IAH (direct and indirect). If there are, you may be put on such flight, and so maybe with small disruption, but if the flight it is next day, you may want to reconsider (value of your time vs. risk).

On the topic of compensation:

The stop in London has no influence: the whole trip from Vienna to Houston is considered as a single trip, and since it departs from the EU, it’s covered under EC261
This means that in case of disruption, they have to rebook you (which they would do anyway, but the requirements are stronger), they have to take care of you if there are extended waits (meals, hotels, etc.), and they may owe you compensation.
Compensation is based on the delay at the final destination and the total distance from origin to destination.

Note however that compensation is not owed in case of extraordinary circumstances, which may include weather-related delays.

there is also no compensation if you get lost roaming through Heathrow's terminals or get stuck in a long queue at passport control or customs.

@jwenting the queue must be unusually long for it to count as exceptional circumstances. And in this specific case there are no passport control or customs, only security.

It might be pretty tight, but if United sold you this ticket they'll take care of you if you miss the flight. My experience with LHR is that it may occasionally get crowded in transfer security checks, and it's something difficult to anticipate. 1 hour is very risky, and any delay of the incoming flight will eat into your very slim time margins. You're right that there's additional security checks at the gate on top of the airport security, but I don't think United will close the gate while there are still people in the queue, so as long as you get to the gate on time you should be good.
Refer to the answer by @jcaron re compensation.

The whole trip is actually covered under EC261 as it’s a single trip departing from the EU, the fact that there’s a connection in the UK doesn’t change anything.

Compensation depends on why you missed it. United may claim that security delays are outside their control.

@Hilmar I don't know why everybody always bring that up. It simply doesn't matter that it's outside their control. The only relevant standard (certainly in EU law) is whether there were “extraordinary circumstances” that no reasonable measures could mitigate. For example, if security delays were foreseeable and they decided to sell the ticket anyway, they would still be on the hook. The EU gives other examples about strikes or technical problems. And even if they don't really care about all this and just want an excuse, “extraordinary circumstances” is still the phrase they would use.

@Relaxed maybe, but getting lost trying to find the correct gate or transfer desk is NOT covered, and a very real possibility.

@Relaxed: it always comes up since most airlines will go out of their way to avoid payment (legally or not). The law was written sloppily: a lot of real world cases are not covered and open to interpretation.  Hence most details are worked out by the courts: see for example https://flightdelaypay.com/leading-cases/

@Hilmar What does? Airlines have lawyers, what they invoke is “extraordinary circumstances“, not “outside our control” because they know that the former is the only relevant excuse (it's right there in case nº2 on the website you mentioned). Also, it's true that many cases are not covered but that isn't only because the law was written sloppily.

The real story is that the court took it upon itself to vastly expand its scope by equating 3-hour delays with cancellations (also listed as “case 4”). Airlines have been arguing about this and trying to overturn or circumscribe this precedent ever since. That's what blew up the whole system and created all the questions about connections, delay at security, minor weather or ATC delays, etc. Under the letter of the law, none of that would ever come up because as long as the flight isn't cancelled, passengers would not be entitled to compensation, plain and simple.

@Relaxed I knew that a lot of the rules we rely on today were decided by the courts rather than being in the directive, but I hadn't realised that "delay=compensation" was in this situation. However the case that triggered (especially the Condor one) really showed the bad faith of many airlines: the flight was actually cancelled (and passengers rebooked on the flight the following day), they alleged lots of reasons which turned out to be incorrect and unrelated, etc. Too bad for them, they should have settled before it went to court. I think most airlines have learned that lesson now.
